# how to tail multiple files in node.js?

Tags: node.js, tail

when use the following code to tail a file, we can successfully output data.

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var filename = '/logs/error.log';
var tail = spawn("tail", ["-f", filename]);
tail.stdout.on("data", function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

but when i change filename to "/logs/*.log", i don't find anything output. who can tell me what is the reason? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When typing `tail -f /logs/*.log` on the console, the expansion of `/logs/*.log` is handled by the shell; by the time the `tail` program gets the arguments, they've already been expanded to `tail -f /logs/error.log /logs/other.log`. You need to do the expansion yourself for Node:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var filename = fs.readdirSync('/logs').map(function(file) { return '/logs/' + file });
var tail = spawn("tail", ["-f"].concat(filename));
tail.stdout.on("data", function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Thanks your answer! but when run your changed code, i still don't find   anything output. so i change filename to '/logs/out.log /logs/error.log', and i also don't find anything output.

Comment: Hey, @Steve, sorry about that! The last argument to `spawn` should have been a single array; I've fixed the example code.

Comment: Or you do something like spawn("bash", ["-c", "tail", "-f", filename]), in which case you can use wildcards :)

Answer (score 0):

Because neither `tail` nor `spawn` know how to expand file names with wild cards into the set of matching file names.  That's normally performed by the shell, so in this case you'll need to do it yourself in code.